# PHP USort gives null warning when array is empty

Tags: php, null, usort

```
    function sort_multi_array($array, $key)
{
  if (is_null($array)) return 0;
  $keys = array();
  for ($i=1;$i<func_num_args();$i++) {
    $keys[$i-1] = func_get_arg($i);
  }

  // create a custom search function to pass to usort
  $func = function ($a, $b) use ($keys) {
    for ($i=0;$i<count($keys);$i++) {
      if ($a[$keys[$i]] != $b[$keys[$i]]) {
        return ($a[$keys[$i]] > $b[$keys[$i]]) ? -1 : 1;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  };

  usort($array, $func);

  return $array;
}
```

I'm building a simple search query however when it reaches the end i.e. no more entries in Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in

How can I test to see if the array is empty and simply return a null result before it reaches the usort line?

thank you!

Comment: But can't be null, right? -> if (is_null($array)) return 0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check before using `usort` if the `$array` is null or not.

```
if ($array !== NULL) {
    usort($array, $func);
}
```

Comment: @Viktor: `null given`... If `!== NULL` doesn't work, try `!empty` or `count($array) > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a check for `empty` data -

```
if (!empty($array)) {
   // process data
}
```